# How to detect shake in iphone browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iphone, shake

There's questions about they're either old or don't give an answer.
I'm not good at javascript, I'm alright at jQuery.

How would I `do something` when a shake is detected in the iphone browser? I'm planning on changing the url and sending the user back to the 'library' page of the website when a shake is detected.

From what I read, Android doesn't yet allow access to the accelerometer in the browser. Chrome for Android just came out last month though, and I'm not sure if it's supported in it yet, so I guess this question is just for the iPhone, and Android if anyone knows if it supports it yet. I'm assuming the same code would work for both.

Comment: So I drop my phone or put it on a table and you change the URL?

Comment: is this in a webview contained within an app, or just a plain old website navigated to within one of many mobile browsers?

Comment: @StealthRabbi Possibly not. Depends on how much shaking is required to trigger the event. ;-) In some applications it's also a trivial matter to go back from library home to wherever they were in the event of accidental trigger. I wouldn't think setting your phone down on a table should trigger it, though. But in the end it's up to Nick to decide if that's a good interaction or not. Who are we to say without trying the application?

Comment: @Sam_D plain old website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using jquery, You can use my js lib https://github.com/GerManson/gShake